# Running service fabric powershell scripts from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, azure-service-fabric

I have the following code to run powershell script (standard `Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1` shipped with Service Fabric project template) from desktop app:

```
using (var shell = PowerShell.Create())
{
    Environment.CurrentDirectory = tmpPath;
    var deploymentScriptPath = Path.Combine(tmpPath, "Scripts", "Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1");
    var command = new Command(deploymentScriptPath);
    shell.AddScript("Import-Module ServiceFabric");

    command.Parameters.Add("PublishProfileFile", Path.Combine(tmpPath, "PublishProfiles\\Local.5Node.xml"));
    command.Parameters.Add("ApplicationPackagePath", Path.Combine(tmpPath, "pkg\\Release"));

    shell.Commands.AddCommand(command);
    shell.Invoke();
}
```

However `shell` contains error after script invocation:

- The specified module 'ServiceFabric' was not loaded because no valid
  module file was found in any module directory.
- Unable to find type `[System.Fabric.FabricObjectClosedException]`

There are another errors, but they caused because `ServiceFabric` module wasn't loaded. But this script runs successfully from powershell window, even without admin privileges with RemoteSigned execution policy. So is there any way to run this script from C# with all modules loaded like in Poweshell ISE?

Comment: I am trying to run the command Copy-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage through c# but I get The term 'Copy-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet. What should be the path tmppath?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try running your desktop app as an x64 application. The Service Fabric SDK is only available for x64 systems.

Comment: Thanks, that helped, I have been struggling with it for 2 days. So it seems that powershell x86 has completely different set of modules.

Comment: Unlikely. More likely that the SF SDK was just compiled against x64.